# Why does web service not return string properly?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, web-services, asmx

I have ajax function that send some string to webservice.

Here is ajax:

```
    var data = "wkt=" + wkt;
    $.ajax({
        url: "....some path",
        type: "POST",
        data: data, 
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('Request Failed.');
        }
    });
```

And here is web service:

```
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class ValveService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string ExecuteQuery(string wkt)
        {
                 return "dummy!";
        }
    }
```

As response I get this string:

```
    "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">dummy!</string>"
```

While I expect to get as response "dummy!".

Any idea why I get this strange responce and how to get only string that was sent from service(in my case "dummy!") ?

Comment: This is an asp.net net question, which I'm not an expert in, so I'll let someone else actually answer the question. However, I'd focus on figuring out why why your service is responding with an XML and not just the string.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365025/return-a-single-string-value-from-a-webmethod-in-c-sharp

Comment: You are telling your AJAX what to expect as the return, but it doesn't look like you set the response headers on your actual return, so it's defaulting to XML. You need to set the content type on the return I believe to plain text

Comment: @Nerdi.org how do I get from xml the desired string?do I have to parse it?

Comment: Well, I am hoping that you can set a ResponseHeader or something on the return from Executequery... check this out though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214384/web-service-contains-additional-string-tag

Comment: and if you're going to parse the XML check out this link: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_loadxmltext --- it might help you a bit with parsing those tags outa there on the return

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure web services only return xml or json. There might be a way around it, setting a response type in the service but I'm not sure. [Edit: I see Nerdi.org already hinted at this.]

When `dataType: 'text'`, the response header is not just text, but `Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8`, and you get xml.

Go for json (which is a string) and work with that.

```
//var data = "wkt=" + wkt;
$.ajax({
    url: "/path to/ExecuteQuery",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ wkt: wkt }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // this will be the response header.
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        // response is a wrapper. your data/string will be a value of 'd'.
        alert(response.d);
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('Request Failed.');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
[WebMethod]
public void ExecuteQuery(string wkt)
{
    Context.Response.Output.Write("dummy " + wkt);
    Context.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Or the method could say its returning a string, and add `return string.Empty;` at the end.